# How to combine multiple queries into same table but different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

So I have two tables that i'm working with.

Users which consists of:
`ID`, `NAME`, `CITY`

Follow which consists of: 
`User(id)`, `Follow(id)`

I am trying to write a query that returns to me a table of the name of the user, the name of the follower's name and the followers city. I have this query written which returns the correct information, but prints it out 8 times for each row and I have no idea why.

Here is a link to my code
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDPgZFknC1ybteWM6hwoFJ/3

```
FROM

(SELECT user.name
 from follow, user
 where follow.user = user.id) as NAME,

 (Select user.name
  from follow, user
  where follow.follow = user.id) as FOLLOWER,

    (select city
    from user
    right join follow
    on user.id = follow.follow) AS CITY;
```

Comment: Can you EDIT THE QUESTION to provide the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

When joining tables it would be better to use the `JOIN` syntax. You can use as your base the follow table and transform it through the use of `JOIN` to display the information that you need. On the following example, you join follow with the user table two times to get the user and follower information.

```
SELECT U.name, U2.name, U2.city
FROM follow AS f 
JOIN user AS U
ON f.user=U.id
JOIN user AS U2
ON f.follow=U2.id;
```